# AppleScript to save active Microsoft Word document IFF there is one

Tags: applescript, ms-office

I use [this](https://gist.github.com/tjluoma/ca9bcbe0d905a759442f) with [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) to automatically save the front-most document in Microsoft Word whenever Word deactivates:

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    if it is running then
        save active document
    end if
end tell
```

This works great *unless* there is not an active document, in which case it throws an error.

**I know I could *ignore* the error, but I would rather not.**

I would like to know if there’s a proper AppleScript way to say something like “If active document exists, then save it.”

I tried Googling but only found this (what I have now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query Word for the count of `document` objects – `active document` is just a convenience shortcut to the frontmost one in that list. Unluckily, Word’s somewhat peculiar AppleScript implementation does not return an empty list object when there is no open document, but `missing value` (AppleScript’s take on `nil`) instead. Taking that into account, the following function queries Word for open documents:

```
on hasDocument()
  tell application "Microsoft Word"
    every document is not missing value
  end tell
end
```

– put that in front of your script and change your conditional to `if it is running and my hasDocument()` and you should be fine.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I have updated the gist at https://gist.github.com/tjluoma/ca9bcbe0d905a759442f